# Trying to get the total number of divs in the html document jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am printing several `div` with php. Then I check how many `divs` there are with jquery. When the time code runs, I remove `box_num_3` from the `DOM`. But the total `div` number still 5. I think it was because the `DOM` in the background was not renewed. How do i solve this problem?

```
<?php
 for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
  echo '<div class="box box_num_'.$i.'">Div</div>';
 }
?>


<script>
 var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var box_nums = $(".box").length;
    console.log("total box->"+box_nums);
 }, 1000);
</script>


<script>
    //TIME CODE
    var timer = 5;
    var cd_timer = setInterval(function(){
        timer-=1;
        console.log(timer);
        if(timer==0){
            clearInterval(cd_timer);
            $(".box_num_3").fadeOut(1000);
        }
    },1000);
</script>
```

Edit: Solved problem, thanks to everyone who answered.

```
$(".box").fadeOut();
//instead
$(".box_num_3").remove();
```

Comment: [`.fadeOut`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) doesn't remove the element(s) from the DOM.

Comment: What should I use instead of .fadeOut

Comment: The solution is in this sentence: _"I remove box_num_3 from the DOM"_ -> https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-removal/

Comment: @exp You could use `e.fadeOut(n)` and then use `e.remove()`, then use `$("div").size`

Comment: @Andreas thank you this solve my problem.

Comment: @exp You can count the elements after hiding them with `fadeout` like in my example.

Comment: Don't edit the answer into the question. Either add it as an answer and accept it (or any other answer that solves your problem), or delete the question if it's just a typo or a minor non-unique problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `length` using the selector with visibility, after wait for the elements to hide.

```js
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var total_div_after = 0;
    $('div.fade').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      total_div_after = $('div').not(":hidden").length;
      console.log('After fade:', total_div_after);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Visible</div>
<div class="box">Visible</div>
<div class="box">Visible</div>
<div class="box fade">(fade)</div>
```

Comment: Try it, this code shows the number of elements that have not been hidden.

Answer (score -1):

```
var container_div = document.getElementById('id_of_container_div');
var count = top_level_div.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
```

To count all divs of a specified class do:

```
var numItems = $('.item').length;
```